# How to install Zend framework in remote server using svn?

Tags: svn, zend-framework

I am new to svn. I want to run the following in a remote ftp server:

```
svn checkout http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk
# ZF Lab, see http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Home
svn checkout http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/laboratory/
# ZF Extras (ZendX components)
svn checkout http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/extras/trunk
```

I just want to install Zend frame work in a remote server using svn. I am absolute beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you will need remote shell access to the server if you are to checkout the ZF source that way. If you're on a shared hosting environment, this is most likely not possible.

Since you have FTP, just copy the files over using that?

Comment: i am using http://members.000webhost.com to test this . I have only access to ftp is there any way to use svn using ftp.i also want to use zf command line tool .

Comment: @Compiler why do you want to know all these things .just install it directly without svn

Comment: @Compiler ,Hello I am asking you, do reply something

Comment: @Compiler: You cannot use zf or svn command line tool simply because you dont have a command line (shell) to begin with (your host does not provide it). The zf tool is simply a code generator. You would use zf on your local machine as usual and just upload what it generated back via FTP. This should be easy enough to understand I hope.